# C++ what is "instantiated from here" error?

Tags: c++, struct, std

I am new to C++ programming, I am wondering what is "instantiated from here" error?

```
struct Data {
    Data(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::map<int, Data> m;
m[1] = Data(1, 2);
```

I got several error messages

- no matching function for call to "Data::Data()"
- "instantiated from here" error

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There is no default constructor for `struct Data`. The [`map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) returns a default constructed instance of its value type, in this case `struct Data`.

Either supply a default constructor:

```
Data() : x(0), y(0) {}
```

or use [`std::map::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

```
m.insert(std::pair<int, Data>(1, Data(1, 2)));
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. If I insert something into a map, if the Key already exists in the map, what will happen? Will it replace the existing value? thanks.

Comment: It will replace the existing value.

Comment: @hmjd is incorrect.  From the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) "Because element keys in a map are unique, the insertion operation checks whether each inserted element has a key equivalent to the one of an element already in the container, and if so, the element is not inserted, returning an iterator to this existing element (if the function returns a value)."

Answer (score 3):

> C++ what is “instantiated from here” error?

That is not an error, but the continuation of the previous error adding extra information. The compiler is adding the `error:` prefix so that it is easier to read (or parse) what lines belong to the error.

You can read the whole block as a single error:

*No matching function call to `Data::Data()` instantiated from...*

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a constructor which takes no arguments.

```
Data::Data(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the error (the "No matching function call" one) became obvious only when the compiler started resolving (*instantiating*) the template `std::map::map()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert an item into a map using `operator[]`, what happens is that the map inserts a default-constructed object for the specified key to refer to, then the value you're assigning gets copied into that default constructed object.

To create that default-constructed object, a default constructor needs to be available. In your case, sine you've specified a constructor that takes two arguments (and not supplied default values for those arguments), the compiler will *not* automatically synthesize a default constructor for you.

Under the circumstances, I'd probably modify your constructor to something like this:

```
Data(int a=0, int b=0) : x(a), y(b) {}
```

Note that you should *generally* prefer initializing variables in an initialization list (if possible) over assigning to them in the body of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> no matching function for call to "Data::Data()"

You need to provide a default constructor. See the answer to this question:

[Template Error: no appropriate default constructor available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215249/template-error-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available)

> "instantiated from here" error

You can only have variable declarations in the global area. You need do that assignment from within a function. Correct code:

```
#include <map>

struct Data {
    Data(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    int x;
    int y;

    Data() {};
};

std::map<int, Data> m;

void main()
{
   m[1] = Data(1, 2);
}
```